# Refer to the manual of configure

Tags: man, configure

I follows an instruction to install shtool

1. Download and extract

   ```
   wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/shtool/shtool-2.0.8.tar.gz
   tar -zxvf shtool-2.0.8.tar.gz
   ```
2. Build the library

   ```
   $ ./configure 
   $ make
   ```

I could refer to make manual by

```
man make
```

How could I reach the manual about configure

Comment: `configure` is a script, not a command, thus there is no man page.

Comment: @Panther This is an artificial distinction.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `configure` script is a script that will configure the software that it was distributed with for compilation (if applicable) and installation.

These scripts are often (as in this case) created by [GNU `autoconf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html) (a tool used by developers specifically for creating portable `configure` scripts), which means that it will have at least a minimum of a particular set of options.  One of these options is `--help`.

```
$ ./configure --help
`configure' configures this package to adapt to many kinds of systems.

Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...

To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
VAR=VALUE.  See below for descriptions of some of the useful variables.

Defaults for the options are specified in brackets.

Configuration:
  -h, --help              display this help and exit
      --help=short        display options specific to this package
      --help=recursive    display the short help of all the included packages
  -V, --version           display version information and exit
  -q, --quiet, --silent   do not print `checking...' messages
      --cache-file=FILE   cache test results in FILE [disabled]
  -C, --config-cache      alias for `--cache-file=config.cache'
  -n, --no-create         do not create output files
      --srcdir=DIR        find the sources in DIR [configure dir or `..']
```

(etc.)

There is no manual for `configure` as it's specific to the software package that it was distributed with. Some available options may depend on the software it configures (so it can't be a system-wide tool with its own manual).  In particular, there are often `--with-xxx` and `--without-xxx` options to configure projects with or without some library `xxx`, and likewise `--enable-xxx` and `--disable-xxx` options to enable or disable certain features (not in this `shtool` distribution though, it seems).

There is often (e.g., in this case) both a `README` and an `INSTALL` text file distributed with the source code.  These files will describe the software and how to configure and install it.  The `INSTALL` document will often tell you how the authors envisage the installation should happen, and you can refer to the `configure --help` output for how to customise this to your own needs.

Comment: **as some of the available options may depend on the software that it configures** This part is crucial.  Almost the only safe thing you can assume will be present on a GNU system is the `--help` option, which in turn will show all of the others.  Thus, they/we never bothered with a man page.

Comment: @TiStrga I believe most, if not all, of the options that I included in the output above will always be there, but it may also depend on the version of `autoconf` used to generate the `configure` tool.

Comment: Indeed, some of those are still "new" to my old brain.  :-)  Technically, `--version` is also required to be there, and in practice the caching controls always have been.

Comment: `--prefix=DIR` is also pretty much universal among `configure` scripts and is an essential argument (unless somehow you're satisfied with dumping everything into the single `/usr/local` tree).

Answer (score 3):

`configure` is a script, not a command, thus there is no man page.

You can find information in the README file and, if the author was kind, a --help option

See https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/configure-command-315662/ or similar for a discussion.

Comment: If `configure` was generated by `autoconf`, then it will _always_ have a `--help` option. A `README` or `INSTALL` file may exist if the author has written and distributed them.  Also, calling `configure` "not a command" is not quite right. It's a command like any other, it's just that it's a _specific_ command for configuring a particular piece of software (and it's probably not located in `$PATH`).  Any command can be a script (`firefox`, for example, is often a script).

Comment: @Kusalananda true, but `autoconf` is not always used, it varies by project as does README and / or INSTALL and / or a clean or remove option(s)

Comment: I'd be surprised if a `configure` script distributed by the GNU people was not built by `autoconf`...

Comment: On my Ubuntu, `which` is a script, but it does have a manpage.

Comment: `configure` is a script _included in the source_ of the downloaded package, so it would be odd if it had a man page installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Well by `./configure` command you are executing a file called configure. This is similar as executing any file so there will be no manual entry as this is not a command. While `make` is a command so you will find manual entry for make.

Comment: There is no distinction between "commands" and "scripts" on Unix systems.

Comment: this clicks with me, there is no distinction among "commands", "function", "script", "program", "process", "routine", "modular", "lib". they are functions in nature. @Kusalananda